# Proving that $[(A \to X) ~\text{or}~(B \to Y)] \to [({A ~ \text{and} ~B}) \to (X ~ \text{or} ~Y)]$ without a truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

I am tasked with proving the following:

$$[(A \to X) ~\text{or}~(B \to Y)] \to [({A ~ \text{and} ~B}) \to (X ~ \text{or} ~Y)].$$

Can anyone tell me what this statement is: Valid, Satisfiable or Un-satisfiable?

I did a rough proof using the identity $A \to X \equiv \neg A \vee X$ and got down to

$$[\neg A \vee \neg B \vee X \vee Y] \to [\neg A \vee \neg B \vee X \vee Y].$$

So this is a valid statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following:
\begin{align}
(A\to X)\lor(B\to Y)&\equiv (\neg A\lor B)\lor(\neg B\lor Y)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (\neg A\lor\neg B)\lor(X\lor Y)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv\neg(A\land B)\lor(X\lor Y)\\[0.5em]
&\equiv (A\land B)\to(X\lor Y)
\end{align}
Can you see how this line of argument proves that $[(A\to X)\lor(B\to Y)]\to[(A\land B)\to(X\lor Y)]$?

Lastly, from the above argument, note that you have $B\lor\neg B$ and more disjunctions...what does that tell you? And since the left-hand side and right-hand are equivalent per the above argument, you necessarily have an implication of the form $T\to T$, which is certainly *always* valid.